# Silverlight ListboxItem Visibility binding

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I am making a prototype of a Silverlight application in Expression Blend 4 and I'm trying to show/hide ListBox/ComboBox items based on boolean values in the data they are bound to. I found an example online which suggested this would work but it doesn't:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrototypeScreens"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="PrototypeScreens.Toolbar"
    Width="640" Height="31">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ComboBox-Sketch}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" ItemsSource="{Binding Sites}" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                    <ed:RegularPolygon Fill="{StaticResource BaseBackground-Sketch}" ed:GeometryEffect.GeometryEffect="Sketch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" InnerRadius="0.47211" Margin="0,0,0,0" PointCount="5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource BaseBorder-Sketch}" StrokeThickness="2" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="10"
                        Visibility="{Binding IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />                   
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock-Sketch}" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,0" />                     
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <!--
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsRegistered, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            -->
        </ComboBox>
        <ListBox Height="29" Margin="0,0,32,0" Style="{StaticResource ListBox-Sketch}" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Sites}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBlock-Sketch}" Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" />                        
                    <ed:RegularPolygon Fill="{StaticResource BaseBackground-Sketch}" ed:GeometryEffect.GeometryEffect="Sketch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" InnerRadius="0.47211" Margin="20,0,0,0" PointCount="5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource BaseBorder-Sketch}" StrokeThickness="2" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="10"/>                  
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <!--
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            -->
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I try to load the screen with this user control, the app crashes unless I comment out the container styles (as in above code). What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** The visibility of the polygon inside the ComboBoxItem works fine.

**UPDATE** I included the xaml for the entire usercontrol

**UPDATE** I got some error details:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2)
Timestamp: Tue, 10 May 2011 15:21:02 UTC


Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Workspace.PlayerWindow.InstantiateScreen(String screen, Boolean showImmediately)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Workspace.PlayerWindow.TransitionScreens(String from, String to)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Navigation.NavigationViewModel.NavigateToScreen(String name, Boolean record)
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///D:/Projects/Expression/Prototype/Bin/Debug/Default.html
```

**UPDATE:** I think I made some progress. It looks like the binding can not be resolved. The ListBox and ComboBox have both `ItemsSource="{Binding Sites}"` and `Sites` is of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<SitesItem>`. `SiteItem` has properties `IsRegistered` and `IsFavorite`.

So I guess the question is: Is it possible to bind to bind to `IsRegistered` and `IsFavorite` in a `ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: Where do you set the static resource for your `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`? Could be that it isn't created before the style is applied. Can you provide details of the crash?

Comment: I do have the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` defined.

Comment: It may be an order issue though. If the converter isn't created when the style is applied, you may have an issue. Might be worth seeing if you can work out in what order things are done.

Comment: Try opening the same project in VS, attaching debugger to blend. Then put a brakepoint into BooleanToVisibilityConverter and see if it gets hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF already comes with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter out of the box.  So simply define it as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Hope this helps